# Constant Shared array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, constants, shared

Is there a way to create a constant shared array? The ovbious way :

`Shared Const GX() As String = {"GS", "GP"}`

Is not working, it says you can't use shared and const together.

If you use only const it says you can't declare a contant array in a class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can create constant variable at application level and have access to that variable in any class inside your application

Comment: If you already know the values to add in the array, why don't you use an `enumeration`?

Comment: Please, type `Const GX() As String` and read the error message you get. As suggested above, you can use an `Enum`; an array of constants goes against the basic `Const` rules.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. An alternative would be to use ReadOnly

```
Public Shared ReadOnly GX() As String = {"GS", "GP"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, you are not able to use Arrays in constants...

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/csfwb0sw.aspx) for details...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the Shared modifier in a Const Statement (Visual Basic), but constants are implicitly shared. Similarly, you cannot declare a member of a module or an interface to be Shared, but they are implicitly shared. [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zc2b427x.aspx) this MSDN Document. You can not use shared and constant in same time